# Notifications failing on two devices

Tags: notifications, ios

I have a question, probably for developers. I have two iPhone 11 Pro’s running iOS 13.1.3. They are exact mirrors of each other using the same Apple ID and iCloud restore.

One receives most third party app notifications, while the other receives 50% of them. I have reinstalled the apps that don’t work on the one device to no avail.

Question is do some apps only register to one Apple ID for notifications, or does the push server think they are the same device because the were restored from the same iCloud backup?  Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Because they’re on the same Apple ID, I believe iOS will send the notification to the device it believes you’re interacting with or that you interacted with most recently.  For example, if you’re working on a MBP with your iPhone next to you and notification comes in, you’ll see it on the MBP and vica-versa.  You can experiment and see if that’s the case here.